# Cleaning package.json "main" for use with require

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, require, package.json

I'd like to keep the path relative and always have it prepended with leading directory.

Let's say I have a string `hello`. It's perfectly valid to have `hello` in your `package.main` in reference to `./hello.js`. However if you take `hello` and require it, it will look for the `hello` node_module and not the file. How can I prefix `hello` with `./` using path? The problem is that the package.json `main` can have these valid options. I'm not saying that these all point to the same files. I'm saying that `hello.js` and `hello` can't be put directly into `require`.

- `../hello.js`
- `./hello.js`
- `hello.js`
- `../hello`
- `./hello`
- `hello`

How can I clean all of these paths so that they work with require?

`path.join` gets rid of leading paths, so that doesn't work. `path.resolve` on the other hand does work to clean all of these paths for use with require, however it makes it into an absolute path.

Expected behavior:

- `../hello.js` -> same
- `./hello.js` -> same
- `hello.js` -> `./hello.js`
- `../hello` -> same
- `./hello` -> same
- `hello` -> `./hello`

Should I just create a regex to look at the path? How can I ensure it would work cross-platform?

```
var pkg = require('./package.json')
// var mainPackage = cleanMain(pkg.main)
// var main = require(mainPackage)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Require paths in node only use forward slashes `/`, even on Windows, so that removes one piece of complexity. Beyond that, the difference between it looking in `node_modules` and looking up a path is whether it starts with a `.` or `/`. ([Docs.](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules)) The clean function could be a simple regex test like this:

```
function clean(s) {
  if (!/^[\.\/]/.test(s)) {
    s = './' + s;
  }
  return s;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense! Thanks!